# Identity transform strange behavior when use with another template

Tags: xslt, transform, xslt-2.0, identity

I have seen strange behavious, by strange mean it act as opposite to the conditions as we do in normally.
following are the details:

> XSLT Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="child[@include='1']"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
    <child include='1'>
        <Attribute>Attribute1</Attribute>
    </child>
    <child include='1'>
        <Attribute>Attribute2</Attribute>
    </child>
    <child include='0'>
        <Attribute>Attribute3</Attribute>
    </child>
    <child include='0'>
        <Attribute>Attribute4</Attribute>
    </child>
</Parent>
```

> And my result is:

```
<Parent>
  <child include="0">
        <Attribute>Attribute3</Attribute>
  </child>
  <child include="0">
        <Attribute>Attribute4</Attribute>
  </child>
</Parent>
```

Acoording to normal conditions we apply the result should be like below acccording to condition

> ```
> <xsl:template match="child[@include='1']"/>
> ```

```
<Parent>
  <child include="1">
        <Attribute>Attribute3</Attribute>
  </child>
  <child include="1">
        <Attribute>Attribute4</Attribute>
  </child>
</Parent>
```

hopefully I have explained in details:
this is the link to the code and xslt processor: [Sample Code](http://xsltransform.net/gWvjQgc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you base your expectations on.

Your first template has a priority of 0.5, while your second (*identity transform*) template has a priority of -0.5.

Therefore the template applied to all the `child` elements whose `include` attribute is `1` is the first template. **This template is empty, so it outputs nothing.** As a result, no `child` element with the `include` attribute of `1` appears in the output.

All the other nodes are matched by the second template which copies them (and by recursion, their descendants) to the output.

Comment: Thanks @michael, this is what I was looking for :)